# Why is this function not running?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, function

Please excuse any key term mistakes here. Even though I have great English I learned programming in my native language.

I have a project running the latest version of Angular, using Bootstrap. I don't know if that's making a difference here or not, I'm really stumped.

I have two separate modals in my component. One of them includes a form to register some data to my DB and has a button with a function bound to it in order to save all the data. It looks something like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addTaskModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Submit a new task</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form [formGroup]="taskForm" class="form-group">
           <!-- Form data and whatnot is in here -->
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <input type="button" value="Submit Task" class="btn btn-primary" (onclick)="submitTask()">
           <!-- ^^ This button is not running correctly -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My typescript looks like this

```
  submitTask() {
    console.log("test");
  }
```

It won't even log to the console. Usually when I call a function that isn't declared in my typescript component, the page won't render and return an error, which is fine. I tried changing the name of the function to something that didn't exist, and for some reason I didn't get an error. I got an error to my VS Code console, but the page still rendered and worked fine. Am I doing something wrong that is plainly obvious? Or is it just that I can't have two modals on one page, although that makes no sense at all?

Comment: Try using (click) event.

Comment: Try using (click)

`<input type="button" value="Submit Task" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="submitTask()">`

Comment: Refer - https://angular.io/guide/event-binding and use event binding correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use the `on` prefix in Angular components.
So it would look like this (simplified):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="submitTask()">Submit Task</button>
```

Docs on event binding: https://angular.io/guide/event-binding

Comment: By the way: It's pretty much a best practice to use the HTML-native `button` tag for buttons. That's why I put it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" value="Submit Task" class="btn btn-primary" (onclick)="submitTask()">
```

Remove the parenthesis between **onclick** and change it to **on-click** as in `<input on-click="submitTask()">`.

alternatively, do `(click)="submitTask()"`

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="submitTask()">Submit Task</button>
```

Refer to the [Event Binding docs](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding)